# Why the timestamps disappear when I try to convert data frame into xts object in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm building a Shiny app that users can upload portfolio weight, yield to maturity and price files, and the app will calculated the realized P&L. I was able to build the realized PNL calculator in R. However, the timestamps of the data frame disappeared while I was trying to convert the data frame into xts object in Shiny.

I used the exactly same function that works in r, but the output does not show the timestamp in Shiny.

Here is my code,

```
library(xts)
library(lubridate)
library(shiny)

# UI part
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Realized P&L with Accrued Interests Calculator"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("weight", "Choose Weight File",
                accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv")
      ),
      downloadButton("downloadDaily", "Daily Weight Download"),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("weight")
    )
  )
)

#Server part
server <- function(input, output) {
  #convert uploaded weight into xts object
  upload.weight <- reactive({
  validate(need(input$weight, FALSE)) 
  uw <- read.csv(input$weight$datapath, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
  uw[,1] <- as.Date(uw[,1], format = "%m/%d/%y")
  uw <- as.xts(uw, order.by= uw[,1])
  })


  output$pnl <- renderTable({
    upload.weight()
    })


  #Downloadable csv of selected dataset 
  output$downloadDaily <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("Daily Weight", ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(upload.weight(), file, row.names = TRUE)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The input weight is something like this,

```
Date        ETF1      ETF2     ETF3
10/18/13    0.99      0.1      0
10/21/13    0.99      0.1      0
10/22/13    0.70      0        0.3
10/23/13    0.70      0        0.3
10/24/13    0.40      0.50     0.10
10/25/13    0.40      0.50     0.10
```

The output that I am hoping for,

```
            ETF1      ETF2     ETF3
2013-10-18  0.99      0.1      0
2013-10-21  0.99      0.1      0
2013-10-22  0.70      0        0.3
2013-10-23  0.70      0        0.3
2013-10-24  0.40      0.50     0.10
2013-10-25  0.40      0.50     0.10
```

However, the timestamps failed to be preserved in Shiny. The output is like,

```
ETF1      ETF2     ETF3
0.99      0.1      0
0.99      0.1      0
0.70      0        0.3
0.70      0        0.3
0.40      0.50     0.10
0.40      0.50     0.10
```

Comment: If these are row names, you have to set `rownames=TRUE` in `renderTable`.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you!